# Which is better, composable vs provide)?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I want to use is_dev valuable in almost every pages.

Which is better, composable or provide?

plugins/common.ts

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.provide('is_dev', process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    ...
```

Then, I can use `useNuxtApp().$is_dev`

composables/useCommon.ts

```
export const useCommon = () => {
    const is_dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    return {
        is_dev,
        ...
```

Then, I can use
`const { is_dev, user, is_login, ... } = useCommon()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use `runtimeConfig` + `useRuntimeConfig()` for this scenario.